# Deutsche Zeitschriften und Zeitungen zur TestDaF-Vorbereitung, hauptsächlich für den Leseteil

Tags: learning, resource, book, proficiency-test

Zurzeit lese ich einige Zeitschriften, zwar "Spektrum der Wissenschaft", "Der Spiegel", "Zeit Campus" und einige Websiten, z.B. [quarks.de](https://www.quarks.de) und [zeit.de](https://www.zeit.de/).

Können Sie mir bitte weitere Zeitschriften oder Zeitungen empfehlen, die für mich nützlich sein könnten, um meine **Lesekenntnisse** zu verbessern?

Die Zeitschriften können sich auf alle für **TestDaf** relevanten Themen beziehen, z.B. Wissenschaft, Technik, Wirtschaft.

Comment: Das sind ganz normale Zeitschriften ohne speziellen Anspruch das Leseverständnis ansich zu fördern. Wenn Du also diese Zeitungen mit Spass und Freude liest, sollte es auch jede andere Zeitschrift tun, die für Dich interessante Themen behandelt.

Comment: Weil deshalb nahezu die gesamte Palette deutschsprachiger Zeitschriften in Betracht kommt, denke ich, dass diese Frage als 'zu breit' anzusehen ist, zumal es keine richtige Antwort geben kann und diese damit auch meinungs-basiert wären (opinion-based)